# Inner grid lines in whole ListView WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I need to implement a ListView with vertical and horizontal lines inside a ListView.
An example of how it should look:

[image: An example of how it should look]

**XAML**:

```xml
    <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}" Margin="0,20,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Столбец 1" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column1}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Столбец 2" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column2}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Столбец 3" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column3}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Столбец 4" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column4}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Столбец 5" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column5}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Столбец 6" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Column6}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Thanks in advancefor any suggestions!

Comment: And how it's looks like now?

Comment: Set the cell template in the CellTemplate property of the column.
There are no other ways in the ListView.
Better use DataGrid with IsReadOnly = "true" mode.

Comment: @EldHasp DataGrid cannot be used because it does not work

Comment: In the sense of "not working"?
What happened to him?
If you cannot explain in English, write here in Russian: https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/